# Git: how to remove several commits

Tags: git

At now i have these commits:

```
A -> B -> C -> D -> E -> F
```

How can i remove changes from C to E, and get these:

```
A -> B -> F
```

Thanks.

Comment: You can get `A -> B -> F'` easily enough, but it won't be the same actual commit as `F`. Have you pushed `C -> ... -> F`, and does that matter to you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in F:

```
git rebase -i B
```

and delete C,D,E from here. then save and quit.

It will create **copy** of commit F through

Answer (score 1):

Removing commits is **disastrous** if history is published. Another approach could be create a branch off B (say my_branch) and selectively cherry pick commit F